# events.js: 141 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to run node 4.2.2 on a Mac OS and i'm not understanding why every time i get this error message:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn /Users/user/Documents/Projects/project-x/node_modules/gifsicle/vendor/gifsicle ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
c12320:project-x user$
```

What's going wrong?
If i run "gulp build" there is this output:

```
c12320:project-x user$ gulp build
[15:13:41] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Projects/project-x/gulpfile.js
    [15:13:41] Starting 'clean'...
    [15:13:41] Finished 'clean' after 160 μs
    [15:13:41] Starting 'build'...
    [15:13:41] Starting 'copy-assets'...
    [15:13:41] Finished 'copy-assets' after 13 ms
    [15:13:41] Starting 'minify-img'...
    [15:13:41] Starting 'compile-css'...
    [15:13:41] Starting 'compile-js'...
    [15:13:41] Finished 'build' after 52 ms
    [15:13:41] 'minify-img' errored after 468 ms
    [15:13:41] Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/user/Documents/Projects/project-x/public/assets/img/dummy'
        at Error (native)

    assets/js/00-bootstrap.js
      line 3  col 5  Missing "use strict" statement.

      ✖  1 error  ⚠  0 warning

    [15:13:41] Plumber found unhandled error:
     Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/user/Documents/Projects/project-x/public/assets/css/develop.css'

    assets/js/dev/lib/lodash.js
      line 13    col 5    Missing "use strict" statement.
      line 13    col 9    Expected an identifier and instead saw 'undefined' (a reserved word).
      line 217   col 12   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 227   col 21   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 249   col 12   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 249   col 17   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 263   col 67   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 374   col 31   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 386   col 24   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 565   col 44   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.
      line 565   col 81   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 577   col 42   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 589   col 85   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 589   col 103  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 589   col 123  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 589   col 143  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 590   col 62   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 590   col 82   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 590   col 102  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 590   col 122  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 590   col 142  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 590   col 163  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 805   col 54   Unexpected use of '>>>'.
      line 814   col 38   Missing '()' invoking a constructor.
      line 995   col 33   Missing '()' invoking a constructor.
      line 995   col 13   The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.
      line 1037  col 42   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.
      line 1063  col 66   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.
      line 1208  col 72   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1208  col 95   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1226  col 36   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1229  col 40   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1229  col 59   Blocks are nested too deeply. (4)
      line 1231  col 36   Blocks are nested too deeply. (4)
      line 1278  col 26   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1291  col 26   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.
      line 1305  col 23   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.
      line 1323  col 66   Missing '()' invoking a constructor.
      line 1340  col 42   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1355  col 32   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1400  col 44   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
      line 1416  col 27   'arrayEach' was used before it was defined.
      line 1678  col 17   Bad line breaking before '?'.
      line 1721  col 29   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1722  col 17   Bad line breaking before '?'.
      line 1737  col 38   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1764  col 35   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
      line 1788  col 24   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1790  col 21   Bad line breaking before '?'.
      line 1793  col 24   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 1793  col 24   Too many errors. (14% scanned).

      ✖  2 errors
      ⚠  49 warnings


    assets/js/dev/lib/modernizr.js
      line 2  col 12449  This character may get silently deleted by one or more browsers.
      line 2  col 3272   Missing "use strict" statement.
      line 2  col 3308   Missing semicolon.
      line 2  col 3368   Expected '{' and instead saw 'if'.
      line 2  col 3509   Expected '{' and instead saw 'for'.
      line 2  col 3548   Blocks are nested too deeply. (4)
      line 2  col 3548   Expected '{' and instead saw 'A'.
      line 2  col 3615   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 3648   Expected '{' and instead saw 'o'.
      line 2  col 3668   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 3772   Do not use Boolean as a constructor.
      line 2  col 3845   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 3851   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 3863   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 3864   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
      line 2  col 3865   Missing semicolon.
      line 2  col 3952   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4036   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4053   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4073   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4082   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4083   Missing semicolon.
      line 2  col 4124   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4137   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4200   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
      line 2  col 4201   Missing semicolon.
      line 2  col 4235   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4237   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 2  col 4246   Expected '{' and instead saw 'for'.
      line 2  col 4261   Expected '{' and instead saw 'hasOwnProp'.
      line 2  col 4292   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
      line 2  col 4246   The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.
      line 2  col 4334   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4360   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 2  col 4393   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4395   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.
      line 2  col 4404   Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'.
      line 2  col 4433   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4435   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 2  col 4453   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 2  col 4551   Do not use Boolean as a constructor.
      line 2  col 4625   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.
      line 2  col 4629   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4635   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4647   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4673   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
      line 2  col 4674   Missing semicolon.
      line 2  col 4691   Missing semicolon.
      line 2  col 4733   Strings must use singlequote.
      line 2  col 4735   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.
      line 2  col 4735   Too many errors. (40% scanned).

      ✖  2 errors
      ⚠  49 warnings

    [15:13:42] Plumber found unhandled error:
     Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/user/Documents/Projects/project-x/public/assets/js/app-load.js'
    events.js:141
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/user/Documents/Projects/project-x/public/assets/font/text/125eafff-7b5a-4c56-8a3a-d3fe11d8c3cc.svg'
        at Error (native)
    c12320:project-x user$
```

That's the output if i enter "gulp build"

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you. What are you trying to do? Run gulp? What tasks?

Comment: As @Andy said, try providing as much relevant info as you can, so that you can get help. What have you tried? What code have you written?

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/user/Documents/Projects/project-x` to fix your  EACCES errors.

Answer (score 76):

Check whether any other Terminal is running other Applications on the same port. This happens when multiple applications trying to access the same port, Its always FIFO.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Its your local port, If localhost:\\3000 is already up and running, you cannot run another app on the same port. you get the above error.

Comment: solved it, had syntax error in this line var port = process.env.port || 7000;

Answer (score 13):

First Look for the other applications is running on the same port may be another node application.

To find the current process running on the same port use:

MAC:

You can try netstat

```
netstat -anp tcp | grep 3000
```

For OSX "El Capitan" or if your netstat doesn't support -p, use lsof

```
lsof -i tcp:3000
```

Then kill the process

```
kill pid
```

> You can try to kill all node process use:

```
killall -9 node
```

Answer (score 1):

ENOENT means that `spawn` was unable to find the binary you are looking for. Make sure that what ever you are trying to `spawn` is in your path.

In this case you probably don't have gifsicle installed.

Comment: I already had installed gifsicle or imagemin-gifsicle, but it doesnt work.

Comment: How are you running this? How did you install gulp? What are the permissions for that folder? `ls -l` will give more information.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem. There was a problem with the permissions for **assets** - if gulp can't take all assets. Then always there will displayed an error.
I deleted the assets manually. I think i must be careful with(out) the "sudo" - command...

Answer (score 0):

this would not pertain to your error, but that error code can also run if a person is running node on multiple servers with the same address at the same time from their terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install imagemagick ?

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error at work on my Mac Book Pro. None of the solutions fixed it. I finally fixed the problem by restarting my computer. I often don't shut my computer off at night and put it in sleep mode so if your computer has been running for a long time try restarting it and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

so it throw an error ,Unhandled 'error' event,which means you need handle the error event,add function on this event and print the error,you will find the reason and your program will act normal.