# getting error while executing ionic App in terminal using command $ionic serve?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have installed

- Node.js
- Cordova
- ionic

After Installation I created a project as

```
$ionic start myApp
$cd myApp
$ionic serve
```

but localhost doesn't load any thing and terminal shows the following error:

```
The port 8100 was taken on the host localhost - using port  instead
Gulp startup tasks: 0=sass, 1=watch
Running live reload server: undefined
Watching: 0=www/**/*, 1=!www/lib/**/*
Running dev server:  http://localhost:
Ionic server commands, enter:
restart or r to restart the client app from the root
goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

ionic $ events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 192.168.1.5
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1221:19)
at listen (net.js:1270:10)
at net.js:1379:9
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:64:16)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:83:10)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [events.js: 141 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290796/events-js-141-throw-er-unhandled-error-event)

Comment: Are you running other applications that could be causing a conflict? Have you tried running this application on a different port by using `ionic serve -p [port number]`, example: `ionic serve -p 8005`

Comment: same error, after changing the port number.

Answer (score 0):

Update your ionic version

```
npm install -g ionic
```

or

```
npm install -g ionic@1.1.7
```

or

```
npm install -g ionic@1.1.9-beta1
```

Comment: nothing wrong with that which version of node you used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the solution
I needed to use the following code before using

```
$ ionic serve
```

first, type

```
$ionic address
```

it will show

```
1)your IP-Address
2)localhost
```

select 1st option i.e. your IP-Address
and now, you can go with $ionic serve
its, working now.

Thanks All.