# Laravel Mix Error

Tags: laravel-5, webpack

Very new to Laravel. Attempting to Larvel 5.4 mix. After running `npm install` and `npm run dev` I get the following error in npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.9
3 info using node@v4.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info predev @
6 info dev @
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info @ Failed to exec dev script
9 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid @
11 verbose cwd /Users/jluser/htdocs/laravel/project
12 error Darwin 16.4.0
13 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
14 error node v4.5.0
15 error npm  v2.15.9
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error @ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the @ dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the  package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And the following error inline:

```
> @ dev /Users/jluser/htdocs/laravel/project
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3

npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jluser/htdocs/laravel/project/npm-debug.log
```

I installed webpage globally. This is brand new installation of Laravel, no modifications to webpack.mix.js or any other front-end files.

Comment: Could you display more of the error message or the npm-debug.log file?

Comment: Added inline error as well as log error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [events.js: 141 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290796/events-js-141-throw-er-unhandled-error-event)

Comment: Similar error. Unfortunately, did not resolve issue. Nothing is running on port 3000 (verified via `netstat -anp tcp | grep 3000`) and the permissions on the `assets` folder is 755 with all files 644.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded Node.js to latest stable version; resolved issue.